# HTML website can't find my PNG images once uploaded to server

Tags: html, ftp, png

[image]

My website works perfectly on my local drive; I can see all my images with no issue. However, when I upload the website via FTP to be live, it suddenly can't see the pictures. I compressed the images, brought in the entire folder zipped, brought in every image separately, uploaded multiple methods... Nothing works. After a lot of digging, I realized that (as shown in the image), the website seems to think that the pngs are text/html files, which explains why they aren't being found. how do I fix this???

Edit - Perhaps someone could just figure out why the website is trying to identify .pngs are text/html files.

Comment: PS my website is unimoonmedia.com . You can see in the first box where the images should be appearing and are not.

Comment: Can you provide your website link so we can identify your problem

Comment: Your first box links to the `about/` directory while the second links to the `assets/` directory. Could the issue have something to do with that?

Comment: @Kurisu no, that was just me experimenting with the issue; no matter where I place those images, they still don't show up as pngs.

Answer (score 0):

**Can you give full image URL**

**For Example :**

Now your image url is : 
G4C_1.png .
you need to change like :
http://example.com/assets/G4C_1.png

Comment: can you please share the image url ?

Comment: I used http://unimoonmedia.com/assets/AWH_1.png (and onwards through 5) to test this method.

Comment: However, this url does not pull anything up because while the .png file does exist in the folder, the code is reading the png as a text file, as shown in the image I uploaded to the original question...